# cross domain cookies Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, cross-domain

I wonder is it possible to get cookies under another domain rather than my current app domain name?

I am building an application which access to another website's api. If the user has already logged in from the other site, my browser will create a cookies under that domain name. For example, user logged in under www.example.com, my browser will store a cookies:
 `cookies['token']` under www.example.com domain. When user visit my website, www.mywebsite.com, how can I get the cookies under www.example.com in my rails server?

Any help is highly appreciate.

Comment: Basically: You can't. The point of cookies having domains is that the browser only sends the cookies that belong to the current domain. Said another way, if you do find a way to read cookies that don't belong to your domain, you've found a security exploit.

Comment: Yes, I have been googling for days, and I found many answers exactly same as you. Great thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done, but it requires the client, your website, and your other website to all work together. You have a client that knows how to authenticate to site A. It wishes to view site B as the user it knows how to authenticate against site A with. The basic way to accomplish this is to have the client contact site A, authenticate itself, acquire a token from site A that site B can trust, and then hand that token to site B.

Effectively, you want to build a very specific case of OpenID or OAuth. This is certainly possible, but you're going to need to make some changes to www.example.com in order for it to play along. If you're able to do this, great.

Start by reading everything about OAuth. You don't need to use that exactly (although you could), but it will help explain what you need to do: http://hueniverse.com/oauth/

Comment: To do this, do I need both site opened? or a link from site 1 to site 2?

Comment: The latter. You effectively need to link the sites. Imagine if site A is a site like LiveJournal, and site B is a site like stack overflow. You can use your LiveJournal account to sign in to Stack Overflow in much the same way I am suggesting you solve this problem. Imagine you click "sign in" on site B. It redirects you to site A. Site A verifies your auth cookie, then redirects you to site B and includes a signed "auth this user as user X" parameter. Site B recognizes that authentication and logs you in to site B. They work together.

Comment: Yes, I got what you mean. It's called `OpenID`, but my problem is site A doesn't provide this kind of service, but it has its own login screen. When a user visits site A, browser will create a cookies, and when user visits site B, I want site B to access the cookies create in site A. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: No. Cross-domain cookies are fundamentally not allowed. I am describing a way to solve your requirement, not a way to enable cross-domain cookies. There is one exception: you could embed an iframe on site B that renders content generated by site A. This would allow site A to read and handle site A's cookie, but the user would think they were using site B. However, there is still no way to communicate between those iframes. Cross-domain cookies are simply impossible directly.

Comment: So it means I can't access cookies cross domain at all, and there is no way to work around that as well even embed an iframe into my website? :(

Comment: Correct. There are many ways to work around it, but all those ways require site A and site B coordinating and working together. You cannot merely accomplish this by modifying only site B for the same reason that you can't allow people to use their Amazon accounts on your site. The web was carefully designed specifically to keep you from doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can share cookies across different subdomains of a domain but you CANNOT share cookies across multiple domain names.

Cookies are stored by the BROWSER and the browser will not allow you to access or store cookies from external domain names. It would be a huge security flaw if browsers did allow you to do this.

You can, however, share session data that is stored on your server between domain names. This may not be completely trivial, but since session information is stored on the SERVER, you can access the information on the server between apps if needed. If your session data is stored in a database, then all that is required is to give database access to both domains. If need be, you could actually open your database to an external domain name and have the external domain directly connect to the database on your server.